# Java GUI storing in an arraylist

Tags: java, user-interface

How do I add,remove and search for items in an arraylist when using GUI? I would like to add user input into the programs arraylist.
Also how do I CHECK TO SEE IF A FILE CALLED INFO.TXT EXISTS -- IF IT DOES -- SET ALL INFO IN info.txt FILE INTO TEXTAREA -- See below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class FinalMainFrame extends  
 JFrame {
     BufferedReader br = null;
private Container pane;
private JTextField textField;
public FinalMainFrame() {
    pane=getContentPane();
            pane.setLayout(null);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menuFile = new JMenu();
    JMenuItem menuFileExit = new     
    JMenuItem();

    menuFile.setText("File");
    menuFileExit.setText("Exit");
    menuFileExit.addActionListener
    (       (ActionEvent e) -> {
        FinalMainFrame.this.windowClosed();
            });
    menuFile.add(menuFileExit);
    menuBar.add(menuFile);

    setTitle("Final Project...");
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    setSize(new Dimension(250, 200));


    JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter Info:");
    label.setFont(new Font("Serif", 
    Font.PLAIN, 18));
    pane.add(label);
    label.setLocation(0, 10);
    label.setSize(100, 30);

    textField = new JTextField(20);
    pane.add(textField);
    textField.setSize(100, 30);
    textField.setLocation(120, 10);

    JButton button1 = new JButton("Save");
    pane.add(button1);
    button1.setLocation(30, 70);
    button1.setSize(150, 50);
    button1.addActionListener
    (
        new ActionListener() {
            public void 
     actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(    
   null,"You pressed: " + 
   e.getActionCommand() );
   try{

         FileReader read = new 
         FileReader("info.txt");
         BufferedReader br = new 
         BufferedReader(read);
            String txt = "";            
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null){
                txt += line;
                line = br.readLine();
              out.println(line);
            }


         String text = textField.getText();
        FileWriter stream = new 
        FileWriter("info.txt");
        try (BufferedWriter out = new 
        BufferedWriter(stream)) {
            out.write(text);
   }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( 
        null,"You entered: " + text );
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {}                   
            }
        }
    );   
    this.addWindowListener
    (
        new WindowAdapter() {
            public void 
       windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {

      FinalMainFrame.this.windowClosed();
            }
        }
    );
         }
     protected void windowClosed() {
    System.exit(0);
               }
      }
```

Comment: please post your code. it will help you to get correct answer and also help others who will face same problemes

Answer (score 0):

When talking about GUI you should think of events. So add user input to your arraylist on a click event or etc.